# How to put 100-digit integer in a loop and add +1 on each cycle?

Tags: c++

Hello ladies & gentleman!
I have this number:
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
and I want to reach 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 with a for loop by adding +1 each time the loop cycles through and print out all the numbers along the way, then the program should stop.
my code is not working properly, please help I am complete beginner so simple answers are good, thanks in advance!

Result I get when I run this code is:

```
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888801
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888811
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888821
```

Instead of:

```
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888889
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888890
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888891
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888892
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string findSum(string str1, string str2)
{

    string str = "";

    int n1 = str1.length(), n2 = str2.length();
    int diff = n2 - n1;

    int carry = 0;

    for (int i = n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        int sum = ((str1[i] - '0') + (str2[i + diff] - '0') + carry);
        str.push_back(sum % 10 + '0');
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    for (int i = n2 - n1 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int sum = ((str2[i] - '0') + carry);
        str.push_back(sum % 10 + '0');
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    if (carry)
        str.push_back(carry + '0');

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    string str1 = "100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    string str2 = "888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888";
    string strXP = "0";

    for (int x = 0; x != 10; x++) {
        cout << findSum(str1, str2) << endl;
        str2 = findSum(str1, str2);
        reverse(str2.begin(), str2.end());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea how to work with str1, I am guessing the error is there somewhere... :(

Comment: This is the closest I've seen a question look like pure spam. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That is more numbers than you seem to think ...

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Funny how each time I ask a question here I get answer: "Go read a book"

Comment: This time it was use your debugger to figure out where your code deviated from the expected behavior. This is a task every experienced programmer does frequently.

Comment: Even if your machine could do 1 billion iterations of the loop per second it would take 3523310220418287389368059078865775973842944923 YEARS for the program to finish.

Comment: Debugging code of others requires considerable time - especially when it is formatted inconsistently. Sometimes reading a book or article that helps you find your problems is better than giving you the exact line where you have a small mistake and saves our time from reading and understanding your code. What will you learn from the answer? In which way others will benefit from it?

Comment: Start with getting one-, two-, and three-digit numbers working. And use vectors of integers instead of strings.

Comment: I recommend leaving the number as text (string).  If you add 1 to '8', you get '9'.  As with fundamental math, you need to check for overflow (greater than '9') and apply the carry to the next (previous?) digit.  You can treat `std::string` as an array to make looping easier.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `BigInteger` representation class to represent large numbers and perform mathematical operations on them.. `GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library` would be able to do what you are asking better than any answer we could give you..

However, for a naive solution, you can use the following which I wrote just for fun.. It works :D  I only support addition just for this answer and it does not support addition of a "negative" which is subtraction. Plain addition will work.

Note: It is not the most efficient way to implement `BigInteger` arithmetic, but it should be fine for an answer. If you want efficiency, check out: https://gmplib.org/

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  BigSimpleInteger
//
//  Created by Brandon Anthony on 2017-09-11.
//

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
#include <thread>


class BigInteger
{
private:
    char sign;
    std::string digits;
    const std::size_t base = 10;
    short toDigit(std::size_t index) const {return index < digits.size() ? digits[index] - '0' : 0;}
    void Normalise();
    inline bool isPositive() const {return sign == '+';}
    inline bool isNeutral() const {return sign == '~';}

public:
    BigInteger();
    BigInteger(int value);
    BigInteger(int64_t value);
    BigInteger(const std::string &value);
    BigInteger(const BigInteger &other);

    bool operator == (const BigInteger &other) const;
    bool operator != (const BigInteger &other) const;

    BigInteger& operator = (const BigInteger &other);
    BigInteger& operator += (const BigInteger &other);

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const BigInteger& other);
};

BigInteger::BigInteger() : sign('~'), digits(1, '0') {}

BigInteger::BigInteger(int value) : BigInteger(static_cast<int64_t>(value)) {}

BigInteger::BigInteger(int64_t value) : sign(value == 0 ? '~' : value > 0 ? '+' : '-'), digits(std::to_string(value))
{
    std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end());
}

BigInteger::BigInteger(const std::string &value) : sign('~'), digits(value)
{
    sign = digits.empty() ? '~' : digits[0] == '-' ? '-' : '+';
    if (digits[0] == '+' || digits[0] == '-') digits.erase(0, 1);

    std::reverse(digits.begin(), digits.end());
    Normalise();
    for (std::size_t I = 0; I < digits.size(); ++I)
    {
        if (!isdigit(digits[I]))
        {
            sign = '~';
            digits = "0";
            break;
        }
    }
}

BigInteger::BigInteger(const BigInteger &other) : sign(other.sign), digits(other.digits) {}

void BigInteger::Normalise()
{
    for (int I = static_cast<int>(digits.size()) - 1; I >= 0; --I)
    {
        if (digits[I] != '0') break;
        digits.erase(I, 1);
    }

    if (digits.empty())
    {
        digits = "0";
        sign = '~';
    }
}

bool BigInteger::operator == (const BigInteger &other) const
{
    if (sign != other.sign || digits.size() != other.digits.size())
        return false;

    for (int I = static_cast<int>(digits.size()) - 1; I >= 0; --I)
    {
        if (toDigit(I) != other.toDigit(I))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool BigInteger::operator != (const BigInteger &other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}

BigInteger& BigInteger::operator = (const BigInteger &other)
{
    sign = other.sign;
    digits = other.digits;
    return *this;
}


BigInteger& BigInteger::operator += (const BigInteger &other)
{
    if (other.isNeutral())
    {
        return *this;
    }

    if (sign != other.sign)
    {
        //return *this -= (other * -1);
        throw std::runtime_error("Subtraction (Additon of a negative) not supported");
    }

    int carry = 0, total = 0;
    std::size_t length = std::max(digits.size(), other.digits.size());

    for (std::size_t I = 0; I < length; ++I)
    {
        total = toDigit(I) + other.toDigit(I) + carry;
        carry = total / base;
        total %= base;

        if (I >= digits.size())
        {
            digits.resize(digits.size() + 1);
        }

        digits[I] = total + '0';
    }

    if (carry)
    {
        digits.resize(digits.size() + 1);
        digits[digits.size() - 1] = carry + '0';
    }
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const BigInteger& other)
{
    if (other.sign == '-') os << '-';
    std::string temp = other.digits;
    std::reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    return os << temp;
}




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    BigInteger bi{"888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888"};
    BigInteger ti{"999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"};

    std::cout<<bi<<"\n";

    while (bi != ti)
    {
        bi += 1;
        std::cout<<bi<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```